# Elasticsearch data aggregation with faceting on arrays

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search

I'm inserting some companies in the index, where the countries attribute is an array of country codes:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/10' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN"], "name" : "company10"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/11' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company11"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/12' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company12"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/13' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN", "HU"], "name" : "company13"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/14' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company14"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/15' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company15"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/16' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company16"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/17' -d '{"countries" : ["BE", "CN", "EN"], "name" : "company17"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/18' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE"], "name" : "company18"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/19' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company19"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/20' -d '{"countries" : ["EN", "FR"], "name" : "company20"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/21' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "DE", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company21"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/22' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company22"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/23' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "HU"], "name" : "company23"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/24' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company24"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/25' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company25"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/26' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company26"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/27' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company27"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/28' -d '{"countries" : ["CN"], "name" : "company28"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/29' -d '{"countries" : ["BE", "CH", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company29"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/30' -d '{"countries" : ["CN"], "name" : "company30"}'
```

I want to aggregate the companies by country_code (countries attribute), count how many companies are present for each country.

Sadly, even this (the count for AT code) doesn't work:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{"query"  : { "match_all" : {} },
 "facets" : {
    "foo" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : { "countries" : "AT" }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I'm getting:

...

```
"facets" : {
  "foo" : {
    "_type" : "filter",
    "count" : 0
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Is only `AT` not working? Did you try `CN`?

Comment: Now, I tried for CN too, same response as for AT in the facets section

Comment: hmm ok, I was thinking it could be due to ES not indexing stopwords (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883936/is-there-a-way-to-escape-elasticsearch-stop-words). But if CN also does not work, then that cannot be the case.

Comment: good catch, thanks, but issue still exists... maybe other idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because filters are not analyzed. `AT` is stopword, so it is not indexed. You can check it using `_analyze` API: `http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=AT&field=countries`.

You can check non stopword, for example `CN`, but this is lowercased `http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=CN&field=countries`. So `cn` (which is in fact stored in index) doesn't match with `CN` in you facet filter.

You can try to modify your search to lowercased country abbreviation:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{"query"  : { "match_all" : {} },
 "facets" : {
    "foo" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : { "countries" : "cn" }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

to get

```
"facets" : {
    "foo" : {
      "_type" : "filter",
      "count" : 15
    }
  }
```

But I think you should define mapping for countries to `"index":"not_analyzed"` to avoid this (both stopwords and lowercasing)

```
# Delete index
#
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test'

# Create with mapping
#
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "countries": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"  }
      }
    }
  }
}'


# Index documents
#
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/10' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN"], "name" : "company10"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/11' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company11"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/12' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company12"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/13' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN", "HU"], "name" : "company13"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/14' -d '{"countries" : ["CH", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company14"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/15' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company15"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/16' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company16"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/17' -d '{"countries" : ["BE", "CN", "EN"], "name" : "company17"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/18' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE"], "name" : "company18"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/19' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company19"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/20' -d '{"countries" : ["EN", "FR"], "name" : "company20"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/21' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "DE", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company21"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/22' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company22"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/23' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "HU"], "name" : "company23"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/24' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company24"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/25' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company25"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/26' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "BE", "CH", "CN", "DE", "EN", "FR", "HU"], "name" : "company26"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/27' -d '{"countries" : ["AT", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company27"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/28' -d '{"countries" : ["CN"], "name" : "company28"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/29' -d '{"countries" : ["BE", "CH", "CN", "EN", "FR"], "name" : "company29"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/30' -d '{"countries" : ["CN"], "name" : "company30"}'

# Refresh index
#
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'

# Search
#
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/company/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{"query"  : { "match_all" : {} },
 "facets" : {
    "foo" : {
      "filter" : {
        "term" : { "countries" : "AT" }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Awesome explanation of the issues, thanks a lot. 
It works like a charm ;)

Comment: i have the same problem, I have added index: not_analyzed for the field 'country_code', thought some countries 'at', 'be', etc were excluded from facets. I'm continue checking. By now I just added `_` before country code, so it stores _at, _be, etc.

Comment: or, @vhyza was right, I just have 2 types - one with provided mapping, and another is autocreated without :not_indexed, my fauld, so yes - index: not_analyzed solves the problem.